# Time Machine always stalling at about 96%, spends a long time reading from NAS backup disk

Tags: backup, time-machine, nas

Just after upgrading to macOS Sonoma, I've noticed that Time Machine has been getting stuck at around 96% completion on its hourly backups. It spends 10s of minutes apparently slowly reading from my remotely-attached RAID array (TrueNAS), making no reported progress, before eventually completing the final few percent. It only ends up copying a few hundred MB of data. Before upgrading, it completed much more quickly. I have verified that the speed of the TrueNAS SMB share has not changed and can easily saturate a gigabit connection.

[image: Activity Monitor network pane]

I have previously had issues with Time Machine corrupting the sparsebundle on the NAS (which I have repaired with `fsck` and subsequently verified multiple times), so I am wary of messing with it during an in-progress backup. So, the fact that it takes so long for these incremental backups is irritating.

Console shows `backupd` repeatedly emitting the following messages every few seconds, though I don't know if this is normal and if it was doing this before.

```
default 00:38:48.999607-0700    backupd [0x7fed94709bc0] activating connection: mach=false listener=false peer=true name=com.apple.backupd.sandbox.xpc.peer.0x7fed94709bc0
default 00:38:48.015192-0700    backupd [0x7fed94709bc0] invalidated after getting a no-senders notification - client is gone
error   00:38:48.015392-0700    backupd com.apple.backupd.sandbox.xpc: connection invalid
```

There are also some "removed presenter" and "removed provider" messages interspersed less frequently.

Has anyone else experienced similar issues, or have any suggestions for debugging this?

Comment: From a preliminary look through a trace of the backupd process with Instruments, it appears to be opening every directory then running fstatat64 on every file in every directory in the previous backup.

Comment: To use SMB instead of AFP for Time Machine it needs to be SMB v4.8 or higher, it came out in 2017 so you probably have that.

Comment: @malhal I assume you mean samba v4.8? I'm using the samba version bundled with TrueNAS 13 which is version 4.15.13.

Comment: I've been seeing what seems like this same stall since upgrading to Sonoma. I'm not using a NAS destination however and I'm only seeing it with one of my two local destinations. So, I'm guessing this stall has little to do with using a NAS destination. See [also](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/467136/230063).