# Will it make a difference if I buy a fast SSD disk for time machine?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine, ssd, sonoma

Since Sonoma, waiting for Time Machine to finish is a hell.

It takes 2 to 4 hours to make a simple incremental hour backup.

I've read that Apple throttles down the backup process.

I have typed this at terminal, supposedly to remove the throttle.

```
sudo sysctl debug.lowpri_throttle_enabled=0
```

but every time the system restarts, this goes back to `1`.

My backup disk is a spinning HD connecting through USB 3.1, so, in theory, I can read/write up to 5Gb/s.

Analyzing Activity Monitor as Time Machine is in progress, I see this:

[image]

with the throttle is disabled.

So, in theory, the disk is being written at 4,8MB/s, that is ultra-low.

I also suspect the current disk I am using may be failing, this is why it is so slow, but I did check it with disk monitor, and it appears to be ok.

Two questions:

- Is there any way I can test deeper this disk to see if it is really ok?
- If I buy one of those SSD thunderbolt 4 disks that can write 10 or more times faster than the one I have, will it make a difference? Considering that time machine throttles...

Comment: Exactly which software are you using to check the health of the external disk being used by Time Machine (TM)? Can you provide a link to its webpage? I am asking because the disk being used by TM should be read-only to all apps other than TM and therefore any test on it may not be reliable without the disk being reformatted first.

Comment: This is not the normal speed I would expect from TM; so it may well be the hard drive. Yes, an SSD will be faster than a hard drive. You don't need to go crazy: any external USB SSD will be sufficient.

Comment: I've been seeing this as well with Sonoma. Interestingly perhaps, I see this slowness problem **only with one of my destination storage devices**. One completes in like 15 minutes while the other in like 55 minutes. So I'm assuming there is a combo of the change to Sonoma with something about the device. Disk utility info for the physical disks and for the logical volumes shows no significant differences to me in this regard however. So perhaps it's something to do with differences between the backup databases on the two volumes.

Comment: Is this due to the same underlying problem as what's described [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/465165/230063)?

Comment: @LouisLangholtz, TM gets stuck at x% for hours but I see no backupd errors on console.